# R Shiny access to RenderUI in Server

Tags: r, shiny

I have an issue in R Shiny command renderUI. Namely, after  setting up the uiOutput and renderUI, I cannot further access to the newly assigned input.

ui.r:

```
selectInput("Vehicle", "Select Vehicle:",List)
uiOutput("cond_input")
```

server.r:

```
rv <- reactiveValues()
 observeEvent(input$Vehicle,{
    req(input$Vehicle)

  output$cond_input <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "cars", "Cars:",
      List[substr(List,1,4) == substr(input$Vehicle,1,4)])
    })

 if (input$cars == "Audi"){rv$model <- "toprange"}
 else {{rv$model <- "midrange"}
 })
```

Issue is input$cars is not detected. And when I end with input$ there are several options available like the above mentioned vehicle but no "cars". I can only access to the parameters defined in ui.R, but not the input parameters defined in server.R through renderUI. However, in other media I have seen that this is possible

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have those lines in the same function? I don't think the elements is immediately added after the `renderUI`. You'd need to access it from later in the life cycle. It would help if you created a minimal [reproducible shiny example](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Creating-a-Reproducible-Example) showing how exactly you are calling these things.

Comment: edited, thanks for looking

Comment: If its outside the observe, then it will not react simultaneously with my first select variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the work or updating the UI and updating your variables based on the UI. Here's an example that runs without error. (I had no idea what was in `List` so I guessed.)

```
library(shiny)
List <- c("Audi A4", "Audi A5", "Ford Mustang", "Ford Escape")
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Vehicle", "Select Vehicle:",List),
  uiOutput("cond_input"),
  textOutput("type")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()

  output$cond_input <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "cars", "Cars:",
      List[substr(List,1,4) == substr(input$Vehicle,1,4)])
  })

  observeEvent(input$cars, {
    rv$model <- if (substr(input$cars,1,4)== "Audi") "toprange" else "midrange"
  })

  output$type <- renderText(rv$model)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will have a thinkaround on this.

Comment: @MrFlick I think this is probably preferable. Remove the outer `observEvent(input$Vehicle` and use `output$cond_input <- renderUI({
    req(input$Vehicle)
    selectInput(
      "cars", "Cars:",
      List[substr(List,1,4) == substr(input$Vehicle,1,4)])
  })`  The assumption in `observeEvent` is the handler expression is isolated, but the expression passed to `renderUI` is reactive